# Установление значения TextView из отдельного потока при помощи Handler

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Имеется код метода:

**UPD 2**

```
    private void onPlayClick(final View view){
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int secs = seekBar.getProgress()*SONG_LENGTH/100;
                while (secs<=SONG_LENGTH) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    int seconds = secs % 60;
                    int minutes = secs / 60;
                    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
                    final String result = String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            curTime.setText(result);
                        }
                    });
//                    view.post(new Runnable() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void run() {
//                            curTime.setText(result);
//                        }
//                    });
                    secs++;
                }
            }
        });
        thread.run();
    }
```

**UPD**

Вот пример метода со `SnackBar`:

```
private void onPrevClick(final View view){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Prev", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Close", snackbarOnClickListener);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.run();
    }
```

**UPD 3**

package asus.example.com.player;

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private Button prev;
    private Button next;
    private Button play;
    private Snackbar snackbar;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private TextView curTime;

    private final int SONG_LENGTH = 120;

    View.OnClickListener snackbarOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
    };


    private void onPrevClick(final View view){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Prev", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Close", snackbarOnClickListener);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.run();
    }

    private void onPlayClick(final View view){
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int secs = seekBar.getProgress()*SONG_LENGTH/100;
                while (secs<=SONG_LENGTH) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    int seconds = secs % 60;
                    int minutes = secs / 60;
                    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
                    final String result = String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            curTime.setText(result);
                        }
                    });
//                    view.post(new Runnable() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void run() {
//                            curTime.setText(result);
//                        }
//                    });
                    secs++;
                }
            }
        });
        thread.run();
    }

    private void onNextClick(final View view){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Next", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Close", snackbarOnClickListener);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.run();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prev = findViewById(R.id.prev);
        play = findViewById(R.id.play);
        next = findViewById(R.id.next);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        curTime = findViewById(R.id.curTime);
        prev.setOnClickListener(this);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.prev:
                onPrevClick(v);
                break;
            case R.id.play:
                onPlayClick(v);
                break;
            case R.id.next:
                onNextClick(v);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
        int seconds = (SONG_LENGTH*seekBar.getProgress()/100)%60;
        int minutes = (SONG_LENGTH*seekBar.getProgress()/100)/60;
        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        String result = String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        curTime.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Задача заключается в том, чтобы при выполнении условия `secs<=SONG_LENGTH` каждую секунду обновлять значение `TextView`. Т.к. из потока `thread` я этого сделать не могу, то использую для этого `Handler`. В случае с `SnackBar` такой способ прокатил, но в этом случае работа программы просто ступорится. Приложение не закрывается, но просто не могу кнопки нажимать и все. В чем проблема и как исправить? И если не сложно - объясните, почему в случае со `SnackBar'ом` это сработало, а в случае с `TextView` - нет.

Comment: `Handler` надо объявлять за пределами потока и делать его final (для доступа). Видимо в `SnackBar`'е так и было

Comment: @Jarvis_J, обновил вопрос

Comment: Другие потоки не имеют доступа к UI и `view` текущей активности, поэтому приходится получать его через `Handler`, созданный в основном потоке. `SnackBar` - UI не использует и может быть доступен даже из другого потока.

Comment: У `View` есть свой метод `post(Runnable)` - с ним потоком не ошибётесь и кода писать поменьше.

Comment: @Jarvis_J, обновил вопрос

Comment: @woesss, обновил вопрос. Попробовал и тот вариант, который присутствует в коде, и тот, который закомментирован. Все равно не помогло

Comment: Я не вижу в этом коде проблем, из-за которых может что-то "ступориться". Уверены что проблема именно здесь? А вообще почему бы не менять текст там же, где меняется прогресс сикбара?

Comment: @woesss, пытаюсь сделать плеер. Поэтому обновляю текст из отдельного метода. Т.е. например пользователь жмет кнопку Play и начинает изменяться значение, которое прошло от начала песни до текущего момента. Возможно не самый рациональный ход, но если есть варианты лучше - готов рассмотреть конечно же. Сейчас добавлю код всего класса, может там где-то ошибка в логике присутствует.

Comment: _ не могу кнопки нажимать _ - в смысле они никак не реагируют (даже не подсвечиваются) при нажатии? Или не показывают snackbar? Если второе, то Вы заблуждаетесь, что _В случае с SnackBar такой способ прокатил_. Хандлеры нельзя создавать в простом потоке, им нужен `Looper`, но даже если Вы его запустите, то это всё же не UI-поток и для обновления `View` такой хандлер не подходит. Объявите один `Handler` как поле класса активности и везде используйте его для обращения к вью. Дальше: методы слушателей (ака `onClick`) вызываются в UI-потоке и в них можно обновлять вью напрямую без извращений

Comment: А от этого таймера можно избавиться так: перенести код из метода `onStopTrackingTouch` в `onProgressChanged` и текст будет обновляться при каждом смещении ползунка seekbar'а (хоть программном, хоть ручном).

Comment: @woesss,  _в смысле они никак не реагируют (даже не подсвечиваются) при нажатии_ - Да, т.е. такое ощущение, как будто телефон просто зависает и все.

Comment: @woesss, `Handler` сделал один, из `onStopTrackingTouch` в `onProgressChanged` код перенес, но проблема осталась та же.